# Incorrect shipping calculation in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have a Magento site which uses the webshopapps matrixrates plugin for shipping rates.

The shipping cost doesn't seem to be calculating correctly and appears to apply a discount to the product cost.

In the screenshot below, the basket contains one product that has a price of €30, the shipping option 'European Airmail' (€5.50) has been selected.

Therefore the total cost should be €35.50

However the cost comes out at €30.55.

It's almost as if the Delivery cost is subtracted from the total (ignoring euro cents)

Interestingly there are two instances of this site, the UK instance appears to work correctly but I can't find anything different in the config.

[image: Order summary]

I've tried comparing a CSV export of shipping rates but can't see anything obviously different.

What do I need to do to get the cost to come out as the correct amount (€35.50)?

Any suggestions welcome!

**EDIT**

If I dump out the quote object, the price for the product shows up as 25

[image: Quote var_dump]

But if I just load the product and dump it's data, I get the actual price which is €30:

[image]

I've got the tax amount with:

```html
<?php

$taxAmount = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');

?>
```

And that comes back as 0.000

So I'm at a bit of a loss as to what is going on here.

Comment: Time to start walking backwards using `die()`

Comment: Thats a bit of a pain because the site uses onepage checkout, so the order totals are calculated on an ajax request, but I guess it might be the only option

Comment: I'm suspicious that 25.05 / 30 gives a very round looking 0.835 which suggests to me that your problem is nothing to do with shipping and more to do with your tax settings.... somewhere with 16.5% sales tax? Just a guess.

Comment: Could be, I had wondered about sales tax but then got bogged down with looking into the code in the Quote model. I'll look into the tax settings. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I've enabled the 'Display full tax summary' option, and now get an additional line in the order summary that states 'Tax: €0.00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to the bottom of this, it was a catalogue price rule for free shipping upto 4.95..

I had removed all shopping cart price rules already but wasnt aware that anyone had created a catalogue price rule so didnt consider it. Thanks for the suggestions guys.